# Windows batch: calling set from within for statement

Tags: batch-file

Given the following batch file which echoes the date:

```
:echo_time
for /f "tokens=2,3,4,5,6 usebackq delims=:/ " %%a in ('!date! !time!') do echo %%c-%%a-%%b %%d %%e 
ENDLOCAL
```

How could it be edited to instead return the datetime to the caller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getDateTime timestamp
    echo %timestamp%

    goto :eof

:getDateTime returnVar
    for /f "tokens=2-6 delims=:/ " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do set "%~1=%%c-%%a-%%b %%d %%e"
    exit /b
```

Comment: This echos: Environment variable 2015-06-29 12 37  not defined

Comment: @user1052610, copied, pasted and executed. I get wrong output because my local configuration should not match yours but it works.